# What to do if a bloc gets too large?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

The [Bloc documentations](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture) suggests creating one bloc for each page.
In my application, a bloc of a page with many features got much too large. Speaking of 300 lines and counting.

How is it possible to split that large class into multiple smaller parts to make it more manageable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try to spilt the UI/presentation layer itself into small subparts. So, then you have smaller blocs for each of them. Also try and refactor some code use functions for reusable code, it might cut down on many lines of code and make the file cleaner and slimer....